# Update whole table to apply new custom save() method

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I just made change to a model with a score attribute to have a new *save()*

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
    if self.id:
        if self.best_rank <= self.rank_level:
            self.best_rank = self.rank_level

    return super(model, self).save(force_insert=False, force_update=False,
                                         using=using, update_fields=update_fields)
```

now I want to update previous records to apply this change,i.e to change *best_rank* from 0 (default).

I tried

```
qs = model.objects.filter(best_rank=0).exclude(rank_level=0)
for e in qs:
    e.save()
```

the problem is that i have 800000 records in that table.

There must be a better way than the one I'm trying

Answer (score 2):

Django has `F()` function that is used in querysets for getting existing fields in record:

```
model.objects.filter(best_rank__lte=F('rank_level')).update(best_rank=F('rank_level'))
```

This code have to update your fields without any for loops

Comment: the problem is that update() doesn't apply save() 
"Be aware that the update() method is converted directly to an SQL statement. It is a bulk operation for direct updates. It doesn’t run any save() methods on your models, or emit the pre_save or post_save signals (which are a consequence of calling save()), or honor the auto_now field option. If you want to save every item in a QuerySet and make sure that the save() method is called on each instance, you don’t need any special function to handle that. Just loop over them and call save():"

Comment: @Progger But what I wrote does what you are doing in save method. So, in that case I think update is proper solution.

Comment: @Progger Of course if you have some signals you shouldn't use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `django-bulk-update` python module

```
pip install django-bulk-update
```

**views.py**

```
from bulk_update.helper import bulk_update

qs = model.objects.filter(best_rank=0).exclude(rank_level=0)
bulk_update(qs)
```